# Can't ping to vagrant box

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I'm trying to create a Vagrant base box following the 2 resources here:

- http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html
- https://github.com/fespinoza/checklist_and_guides/wiki/Creating-a-vagrant-base-box-for-ubuntu-12.04-32bit-server

Using Ubuntu 12.10 (with LAMP) as the OS, I have 1 problem. I couldn't ping the vagrant IP which is 10.0.2.15 although I could SSH via `vagrant ssh`.

How do I set it up such that I could access the web server from my host?

VirtualBox: 4.2.10
Guest OS: Ubuntu12.10
Host: OSX 10.8.3

Comment: Does http://superuser.com/a/705625/103551 contain the solution? If so, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I think it was weird staleness of IPs. After changing the IPs (which were arbitrary anyway), it started working again: https://superuser.com/a/1214376/74576

Answer (score 17):

You can't just access a Vagrant box with its IP address from the host system. Vagrant's networking is meant to define an abstraction layer that works across multiple providers.

The easiest way to access services on your Vagrant box is to configure port forwarding. In your Vagrantfile, see the section *Vagrant.configure* and set values for `config.vm.network :forwarded_port`. For example, the following configuration forwards port 4567 on your local system to port 80 on the Vagrant box:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 80
end
```

After making this change, run `vagrant reload` to apply the changes. After applying the change, you should be able to point your web browser to `http://127.0.0.1:4567` to have the Vagrant Apache instance serve a web page. You can read a bit more about this in the [Vagrant V2 documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/networking.html) or  on the [Vagrant networking page](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, just with the private network setup and the static IP. The IP address I used for months (`192.168.10.10`) was suddenly unreachable, although I was able to access the virtual machine with `vagrant ssh`.

Changing the static IP to `192.168.10.192` solved the problem. The solution here was to change the IP so it doesn't collide with any other machine on the same network.

[Here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) you can find the following notes:

> It is up to the users to make sure that the static IP doesn't collide with any other machines on the same network.
>
> While you can choose any IP you'd like, you should use an IP from the reserved private address space. These IPs are guaranteed to never be publicly routable, and most routers actually block traffic from going to them from the outside world.
>
> For some operating systems, additional configuration options for the static IP address are available such as setting the default gateway or MTU.
>
> > **Warning!** Do not choose an IP that overlaps with any other IP space on your system. This can cause the network to not be reachable.

In Vagrantfile you can configure the static IP like this

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.192"
end
```

Or, in case you're using Homestead like I do, just update your `Homestead.yaml` configuration file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.192"
# the rest of the configuration...
```

And a quick note for the end - my issue possibly wasn't identical as the one here, but since I stumbled upon this question, probably other users will too.

Answer (score 3):

I had to manually start the network on my host-system as `ip addr` showed it was DOWN:

```
sudo ip link set up dev vboxnet0
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/networking.html

I just needed to set up port forwarding.

Comment: While this obviously answers the question, it would be preferred if you would summarize the contents of that link, and post the link as just a reference; that way, if the link goes down, this answer still has merit

Comment: link only answers = bad, what happens when the link dies?

Answer (score 1):

I think this source can help : http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/host_only_networking.html

good luck ;)

Comment: Please describe procedure here because links often end up being dead.

Comment: Please, do not provide answers that are just links. Here's some reasons: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was [enabling bridged networking](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html#dhcp) in the `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

on Ubuntu 12 host/Ubuntu 12 guest the following worked for me with discourse

I add host IP determined by vagrant and guest IP determined by Vagrant to firewall exceptions

Comment: Please give details and not just one-line answers.  http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer